# joomla backend can't login after modifying live_site

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, configuration, joomla3.0

I'm using a justhost.com host for my joomla 3.* website. I have been building my website in a subdirectory of the public www folder. Everything was working fine, until I "published" the website to the root folder of the domain. I had to modify the $live_site variable to point to the root of the domain and place an .htaccess file there in order for my subdirectory to not appear in the url. After I did this everything keeps working but I cannot login from the back-end. After I click the "login" button, the resolved domain points to "administrator" from the root folder and therefore it can't find the administrator component.

Speaking more practically:

this is my domain: 
http://mydomain.com

which is mapped to this folder on the server: 
.../www/

this is the subdirectory in which I built the website: 
.../www/mydomain.com

I added the following lines to .../www/.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mydomain.com/index.php [L]
```

And I modified .../www/mydomain.com/configuration.php:

```
$live_site = 'http://www.mydomain.com';
```

After all this, I can reach http://mydomain.com/mydomain.com from http://mydomain.com/, but when I try logging in from http://mydomain.com/mydomain.com/administrator/index.php it resolves to http://mydomain.com/administrator/index.php and therefore it doesn't let me log in.

I hope this is clear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It took one more line in .../www/.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^administrator/(.*)$ /mydomain.com/administrator/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check Your User Name and Password

In Joomla after you put in your server and if your server system setting is old far it does not respond Warning
''**The combination of username and password is not correct or you do not have an account.**"
so check that!!! for exemplify   Check the site esche.org.et and enter a user name and password it does not respond the warning instead go to esche.org.et/index.php  but i manage that website with the correct password and user name it will lead you to administrator console.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm sure that the username/password I use are correct because everything works if I set $live_site = ''. The only thing is that in this way I see my subfolder in the url, which I want to avoid.